# TeamCity - publishing to Artifactory forbidden

Tags: teamcity, artifactory

I've set up a build feature for this feed with its credentials, also supplied the correct API key from Artifactory, yet my `PUT`s are `Unauthorized`.  I see no other settings for credentials than the two listed, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes, try to this outside of TeamCity, using a different client like JFrog CLI. This may provide a hint as to the source of the issue. Also, have a look at the Artifactory logs, specifically the requests log, to see that Artifactory indeed receives the user. The logs are accessible from the Artifactory UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Check your LDAP is configured properly
2. Open Artifactory "Admin" tab
3. Set the build releated user account in a group (e.g. build_accounts) under the "Group" menu item
4. Set the related repositories and the permission of the group under "Permissions" menu item

If you can not use LDAP you have to set the user/pw in the related settings file.